# Limit number of selected items in ng-grid

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui, ng-grid

Is there a way to limit the number of selected items in **ng-grid**?

I did not find a **setting** to do that, so I am trying to prevent it using a `watchCollection` in `gridOptions.selectedItems`.

When the `length` of `selectItems` is greater than 5, I try to **deselect** the last selection but is not working as expected because the item row index seems to be different as rendered:

This is the watcher code:

```
 $scope.$watchCollection('gridOptions.selectedItems', function (newVal, oldVal) {
   if ($scope.gridOptions.selectedItems.length > 5) {
     for (var i = 0; i < $scope.importableFilesData.length; i++) {
       if ($scope.importableFilesData[i] === newVal[0]) {
         $scope.gridOptions.selectRow(i, false);
       }
    }
 }
```

Comment: Add your code to fiddle please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution using `beforeSelectionChange` property. This property let you set callback that is triggered every time a row is selected. If your return `false`, the selection will be canceled.

```
$scope.gridOptions = {
  // your grid options ... 

  beforeSelectionChange: function (row) {
    if ($scope.gridOptions.selectedItems.length > 5) {
      return false;
    }
    return true;
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your condition in this way. So, you don't have to search last selected row and you can deselect it directly. i've tested it and is working in this way.

```
$scope.yourGridApi.selection.on.rowSelectionChanged($scope,function(row){
        if($scope.yourGrid.gridOptions.selectedItems.length>=5){
           row.isSelected = false;
        }
      });
```

Comment: Thank for the answers, unfortunately this is for the new version (ui-grid) and is not supported by ng-grid.